# dns cache problems on the dnsmasq?

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

Dnsmasq have been installed on my os.
`cache-size=1024` was written in /etc/dnsmasq.conf.
1.how to list all the dns cache on my dnsmasq?
2.how to keep the dns cache expiration till  3600 seconds on dnsmasq?

Answer (score 1):

To dump the cache of **dnsmasq**, you have to need to enable log-queries.

Then type:

```
# kill -SIGUSR1 `pgrep dnsmasq`
```

Also for keep the TTL for cache expiration to 3600 seconds, you need to start dnsmasq with:

```
--max-cache-ttl=<time>
```